# Make The Logic Inside The Tags {% Raw %}...{% Endraw %}

Tags: logic, shopify, raw

In **shopify**.

I have some of the code wrapped in a `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}` tag, but I need to make logic through if inside that tag. It goes like this:

```
{% raw %}
...
{%- if any != 0 -%}...{%- endif -%}
...
{% endraw %}
```

But this way the logic code is **escaped**.
Please tell me how I can make the logic inside the `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}` tags.

Thank.

Comment: First off. You fail to show what any is. No one can help you therefore. Secondly, you say the logic code is escaped. That is hardly understandable either. Suggest you paste your actual code. Otherwise, no one can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The whole idea of a `{% raw %}` tag is to ignore any liquid code inside of it to prevent syntax conflict with other languages.

If you want to execute any code you have to write it outside the raw tag.

Or to say it simply:

```
{% raw %}
...
{% endraw %}
{%- if any != 0 -%}...{%- endif -%}
{% raw %}
...
{% endraw %}
```